# Получение первого символа из атрибута NAME тега INPUT("35165" >>> "3")

Tags: html, javascript

Есть текстовое поле:

> `<input type="text" id="777" name="3.2015-24-02" value="alpha">`

Мне нужно получить первую цифру из ID текстового поля через Javascript:

> `var txt = document.getElementById("777").name;
> var cell = txt.~ПЕРВАЯ ЦИФРА~`

Напишите, пожалуйста, код, который поможет мне присвоить переменной 'cell' первую цифру из атрибута 'name' текстового поля. В данном случае должно быть так: `var cell = "3";` (т.к. имя текстового поля начинается на 3). Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var txt = document.getElementById("777").name;
var cell = txt[0]
```